# Error in keys[abs(list.i), i] <- sign(list.i) in scoreItems

Tags: r, psych

I recently received this error when running the scoreItems function from the psych package in R:

```
Error in keys[abs(list.i), i] <- sign(list.i) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

This is my reproducible example:

```
mykey <- data.frame(scale1 = c(0,1,1), scale2 = c(1,1,0)) 
mydata <- data.frame(item1 = c(1,1,2,3,5), item2 = c(5,5,5,4,3), 
     item3 = 1:5) 
test <- scoreItems(mykey, mydata) # throws error
```

I was getting the error when running code where I used to get no error. I had upgraded to version 1.6.12 of the package.

What causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in version 1.6.12 and perhaps other versions a feature was added to the psych package that allows you to more flexibly specify the scoring key using lists. However, the code that checks whether the key is a list also interprets a data.frame as a list. The following line can be seen in the source code:

```
 if(is.list(keys)) keys <- make.keys(items,keys) #added 9/9/16
```

As such it inappropriately passes data.frames to `make.keys()`, which is only intended for standard lists.

I’ve reported the bug, so hopefully it will be corrected in future.

In the meantime, the simple fix is to make sure that the scoring key is a matrix rather than a data.frame (assuming that the key was k by p matrix where k is the number of variables being scored, and p is the number of derived variables being created).

E.g.,

```
test <- scoreItems(as.matrix(mykey), mydata)
```